# Handle error when Outlook is not available

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have a macro that works when I am at the office.

When working from Remote system we don't have Outlook and it will generate a error that it isn't possible to create an Outlook mail.

I need a MsgBox that says on the Remote there is no Outlook and then exit sub.

```
Sub Mail_workbook_Outlook_1()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim bodystr As String
    
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    bodystr = "Test"
    
    ActiveWorkbook.Save

    On Error Resume Next
    
    With OutMail
        .To = Worksheets("Test").Range("D25")
        .CC = Worksheets("Test").Range("D26")
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = Worksheets("Test").Range("D10")
        .HTMLbody = bodystr
        .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
        .Send  
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

I tried:

```
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    If OutApp Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Outlook is not open, Open Outlook and try again!"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    End If
    
    bodystr = "Test"
        
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    
    On Error Resume Next
        
    With OutMail
        .To = Worksheets("Test").Range("D25")
        .CC = Worksheets("Test").Range("D26")
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = Worksheets("Test").Range("D10")
        .HTMLbody = bodystr
        .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
        .Send  
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, please:

```
   On Error Resume Next
     Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
     Set Outmail = Outapp.Createitem(0)
    If Err <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0
        MsgBox "No  Outlook Application installed, or not configured": Exit Sub
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
```

Comment: I added this, but then the macro fails again at the row Set Outmail = Outapp.Createitem(0).

Comment: This means that Outlook is installed! It is not configured... I will change it to solve that.

Comment: Is there also a possiblity to look first if the app is installed if not then get a msgbox? We are working with 2 options one normal pc then there is outlook and Remote and then there is no outlook app.

Comment: @Karel Jansen: Yes, we must put both lines to be checked. Iwill adapt the code...

Comment: @fanuDuru, could you help me with that please, i'm already hours working on it but i couldn't figure it out haha!

Comment: @Karel Jansen: With pleasure, but I need to know what does not work as you like. Would you like to have different messages for each case? Or, what?

Comment: i got a error At the set outmail = outapp.createitem(0). It says can't create message because datasource isn't found. On the normal pc the code is working fine. Currently i have attachted your first piece of code on the set outapp. I hope this is clear enough haha!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209841/discussion-between-faneduru-and-karel-jansen).

Comment: @Karel Jansen: please delete all comments, except the one saying it works